Magento 2.4.6 installation issue
I have a problem with Magento 2.4.6 installation. Any idea how to fix this?
Xampp: 8.2.12, Php: 8.2.12, MariaDB: 10.6, Elasticsearch: 8.11
[Progress: 461 / 927]
Installing search configuration...

There is an error in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch.php at line: 102
Class "Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder" not found#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch.php(115): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->getElasticsearchClient()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch.php(129): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->ping()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch\Setup\Validator.php(41): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->testConnection()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Search\Model\SearchEngine\Validator.php(63): Magento\Elasticsearch\Setup\Validator->validate()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\SearchConfig.php(79): Magento\Search\Model\SearchEngine\Validator->validate()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\SearchConfig.php(69): Magento\Setup\Model\SearchConfig->validateSearchEngine()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1210): Magento\Setup\Model\SearchConfig->saveConfiguration(Array)
#7 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSearchConfiguration(Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(388): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand.php(237): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(298): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1040): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(301): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Console\Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(171): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\bin\magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#16 {main}


Use elastic search version 7.19 it will work. Though, the official doc suggests opensearch but the Magento 2.4.6 version is also supported with elasticsearch 7.19
Please try with below config and it should work :-
Composer : 2.2 
elasticsearch: 7.19 
mysql  Ver 8.0.21 
PHP : 8.2
Here is the official doc ref for the magento2 system requirements: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements

Do you have Xampp? Doesn't work, tested now with elasticsearch 7.9.0, 7.17.19.

yes and it's working for me with my local instance, additionally sharing a blog here you can refer for installation https://cloudkul.com/blog/learn-magento-2-4-installation-on-windows/

How? This works for me (composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch:^7.0) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600213/class-magento-elasticsearch7-model-client-clientbuilder-not-found0

This is the MAgento 2.4.6 System Requirements :
Composer : 2.2
OpenSearch : 2.5
MariaDB : 10.6
PHP : 8.1 or 8.2

I think your MariaDB is not according to requirement, so make it above version and then try to install.
You can check complete requirement from here : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements

Doesn't work, MariaDB 10.6 installed now. I think it's Elasticsearch issue.

The above error mention about Marian DB that why I told you accordingly. You can check complete requirement from here : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements

Hey Peter,
Please change your elasticsearch version to 7 instead of 8.
yes, in my local with xampp I installed many projects with elasticsearch 7.
my all sites in 2.4.5 version. so it is almost same as like you.

as per official docs, below are the required configuration for 2.4.6**

Composer : 2.2
elasticsearch: 7.19
mysql Ver 8.0.21
PHP : 8.2

change elasticsearch version and it will work for sure.

Check that Elasticsearch is working. As per the below error message, the Magento class tried to test the Elasticsearch connection but it failed as you can see in the error.
I installed Magento 2.4.7 with Elasticsearch 7.17.19 and it is working without any error.
There is an error in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch.php at line: 102
Class "Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder" not found#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch.php(115): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->getElasticsearchClient()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch.php(129): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->ping()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-sample-data-2.4.6\app\code\Magento\Elasticsearch\Setup\Validator.php(41): Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch->testConnection()

Do you have Xampp? Doesn't work, tested now with elasticsearch 7.9.0, 7.17.19.
